# Style custom-controls like standard controls

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How can I get hold of the styles settings for the standard controls (map, satellite etc) so that I can make my custom-controls always look like the standard ones?  I want my controls to look like part of the API, and always matching regardless of platform, and not something added as an afterthought.
Thanks,
Papadeltasierra.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome Developer Tools, Firebug for Firefox, Developer Tools in Internet Explorer, etc. All of these options allow you to inspect the styles for the map controls.

Comment: Thanks Chad.  You're quite right and I've not gone back to this for sometime but I seem to remember that I would have had to effectively recreate the styles myself which seemed silly at the time.  Perhaps Google has exposed them in a nicer manner now so that we can create styles which match their own.